# Add week to a date vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, date, ms-access

I'm currently making an event program in VB.NET where the user can add daily/weekly/monthly/yearly events to a database.
Their are two options :
-Adding the occurrence x times to a StartDate.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZmuI.png^])
-Adding the occurrence between a StartDate and an EndDate.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUko3.png^])
When i'm adding the weeks from 2 april until 29 of may / 2 april x times it generates some random values in it. Is there any way of fixing this ? 
This is my code :

```
Case rbnWeekly.Checked 'Weekly mode with Enddate and StartDate
                If rbnStartEnd.Checked = True Then
                    Dim startDate As Date = dtpStartDate.Text
                    Dim endDate As Date = dtpEndDate.Text
                    Dim currDate As Date = startDate
                    Do While (currDate < endDate)
                        SQL = String.Format("INSERT INTO tblManual (StartDate, EndDate, UniqueID) VALUES (#{0}#, #{1}#, '{2}')", currDate, endDate, id)
                        scmdRecurrence.CommandText = SQL
                        Valueee += 1
                        scmdRecurrence.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        currDate = currDate.AddDays(7)
                    Loop
                    MsgBox(Valueee.ToString & " records toegevoegd")
                Else 'Weekly mode with x times
                    Dim aantal As Integer = txtHerhaling.Text
                    Dim startDate As Date = Date.Today
                    Dim endDate As Date = startDate.AddDays(aantal * 7)
                    Dim currDate As Date = startDate
                    Do While (currDate < endDate)
                        SQL = String.Format("INSERT INTO tblManual (StartDate, EndDate, UniqueID) VALUES (#{0}#, #{1}#, '{2}')", currDate, endDate, id)
                        scmdRecurrence.CommandText = SQL
                        Valueee += 1
                        scmdRecurrence.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        currDate = currDate.AddDays(7)
                    Loop
                    MsgBox(Valueee.ToString & " records toegevoegd")
                End If
```

Comment: Please also see the standard warnings about avoiding SQL Injection via sql parameters.

Answer (score 1):

In the SQL, you need properly formatted string expressions for the date values to be inserted:

```
.. , currDate.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd"), endDate.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd"), id)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but i have one more question, if i'm looking into the database it does not save it as an "yyyy/MM/dd" format but as a "dd/MM/yyyy" value, why is it doing that ?

Comment: It is saving it as a datetime value. This has no format. The format is for display only. If no format is specified, the default settings of your Windows is used.